# Identity Server 4 for NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, express, identityserver4

I'm trying to figure out how to do the identity server 4 authentication below using NodeJS - way out of my comfort zone here.

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults
.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(
         options =>
         {
          options.Authority = "<authority-url>";
          options.ApiName = "<api-url>";
          });
```

I'm missing something in the flow here as the C# implementation isn't provided a secret or similar - so the token is probably verified via identity server? How would I verify the token using NodeJS if I don't have a 'secret' to verify it with?

I've stumbled on [introspection endpoint](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/introspection.html) - am I heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the jwks -endpoint and it's public keys to verify tokens and then I also found a nice [package](https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa) that I used to prepare the middleware:

```
private issuer: string = process.env.idsrv;


auth = jwt({
    secret: jwksClient.expressJwtSecret({
        cache: true,        // see https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa#caching,
        cacheMaxAge: ms('24h'),
        rateLimit: true,    // see https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa#rate-limiting
        jwksRequestsPerMinute: 100,
        jwksUri: `${this.issuer}/.well-known/jwks`
    }),

    // validate the audience & issuer from received token vs JWKS endpoint
    audience: `${this.issuer}/resources`,
    issuer: this.issuer,
    algorithms: ["RS256"]
});
```

Comment: hi,could you please answer this question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495822/validate-identity-server-token-in-nodejs-api    , is there any article to learn what I have to do ? thanks .

Comment: Do you have a solution using 'openid-client' ?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted question is right. but i wanted to fix some of it's trial errors.
you can easily (it took me 4 days) add authentication to your `express api` with `ids4`.
it's how its work:

creating a middleware:

```
const jwt = require("express-jwt"),
jwksClient = require("jwks-rsa");

const auth = jwt({
  secret: jwksClient.expressJwtSecret({
    cache: true, // see https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa#caching
    rateLimit: true, // see https://github.com/auth0/node-jwks-rsa#rate-limiting
    jwksRequestsPerMinute: 2,
    jwksUri: `${issuer}/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks`,
  }),

  audience: "api1.resource", // <---- its your api resource.
  issuer: issuer, // <----- address of identityserver4.
  algorithms: ["RS256"], //<----- its needed algorithm to handle secret.
});
```

The following `auth middleware` is like following code in .net:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults
.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(
         options =>
         {
          options.Authority = "<authority-url>";
          options.ApiName = "<api-url>";
          });
```

to secure a `nodejs` route you can use following example:

```
// this is the secured route by identityserver4
// the jwt module set the ids4 auth result in req.user object
// so you can use it to access logged in user claims and stuff.
// for example testing with client credentials it return some info about the jwt token sent to the /me endpoint.
app.get("/me", auth, (req, res) => {
  const user = req.user;
  debug("req.user: %O", user);

  return res.json(user);
});

// this a unsecured route. so anyone can call this route without any restrictions.
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.send("Hello");
});
```

It takes me so long to find how to secure `nodejs` or express with `identityserver4` but it was as simple as it look like.

The code here is from the following `identityserver4` community example with full `ids4` and `node api` and javascript client and .net console client:
https://github.com/lyphtec/idsvr4-node-jwks

There is a good documentation about this example in its own `github` repository too.

You can download the `node api` and run it with `yarn start` or `npm run start`.

I tested it with client credentials flow and it worked like a charm.

Wish all of you luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only to validate your token you can use the following [**package**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/token-introspection):

```
npm install token-introspection --save
```

This package is configured with endpoint and client credentials, and a function is returned.
Calling that function with token, and optional token_type_hint will return a Promise.

```
const tokenIntrospection = require('token-introspection')({
    endpoint: 'https://example.com/introspect',
    client_id: '<Client ID>',
    client_secret: '<Client Secret>',
});
 
tokenIntrospection(token).then(console.log).catch(console.warn);
```

**Example :**

Here is a middleware to validate the token :

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    
    const token = "wEvxS0y2TkvCjLpKP33oGTK0BcKUb6MHt1u3AeMu8h4"; // get your token from your request 

    const tokenIntrospection = require('token-introspection')({
        endpoint: 'http://localhost:5000/connect/introspect',
        client_id: 'api1',
        client_secret: 'apisecret',
    });
    tokenIntrospection(token).then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        next();
    }).catch(console.warn);
}
```

then you can use it as below :

```
const auth = require('./atuh')

app.get('/', auth, (req, res, next) => {
    res.send("Hi");
})
```